# Convert For Each into For

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
foreach( $project->states as $state ) :     
    echo $state->name;
endforeach;
```

How would I convert this foreach loop into a for loop and still extract the `name` with the index of the loop?

Comment: Why do you have `<?php` in there? You're already in PHP code.

Comment: Depends on what exactly `$project->states` is; is it a numerically indexed array or associative array? And why would you want to convert it in the first place?

Comment: That entire piece of code is goofy :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a numerically-indexed array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($project->states); $i++) {
    echo $project->states[$i]->name;
}
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, though. If you need to get the index, you can do that with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($project->states as $i => $state)
```

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure that `$project->states` is numerically-indexed array by using `array_values` function.

example :

```
<?php
$arrStates = array_values($project->states);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrStates); $i++) {
    echo $arrStates[$i]->name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Very simple one.

Just difference is to count all elements of an array first before to use it.

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < count($project->states); $i++)
{
    //write operation
}
?>
```

Thanks!